# my samsung galaxy plus battery draining quickly some time it is showing 50% but immidiatly 0%

Tags: 2.3.3-gingerbread

my samsung galaxy S plus battery draining quickly some time it is showing 50% but immidiatly 0% so please help me to solve this

ITS GINGERBOAT MODEL GT-i9001
yog

Comment: So it shows 50% and then literally the next second turns off..? What are the actual times? What apps does your battery manager say is using up the most battery?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information but to venture a guess -how old is the battery? Batteries don't last forever.  What radios (GPS, Bluetooth and so on) are running?